# Very Simple jQuery .load Example Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think this is a very simple question, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I need to use JavaScript (specifically jQuery, apparently) to grab some content from a page, and pull it into another page.  I've researched this quite a bit, but can't seem to get even a very simple example to work.

Here is the page I'm trying to get content from:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the test html page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the page I'm trying to use to pull the content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>PullData</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</head>
<body>

<ol id="result"></ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#result').load('test.html');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page it doesn't seem to do anything.  I'm basically trying to follow the examples from jquery.com: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Both html pages are in the same folder somewhere on my C drive.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What browser are you using?

Because of same-origin policy, some browsers won't permit AJAX requests to `file:///` URLs, even if the original file was loaded that way.  I know this is true of Chrome, but haven't tested others.

What does your `.load()` error handler say?  Oh...

Comment: I was using Chrome.  Tried it in Firefox and it works (after adding the closing script tag I was missing in this example).  This was the main problem.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome.  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416 for more info

Answer (score 4):

It seems to make logical sense.

Checking the API on load you may want to see if it actually loads, or if it encoutners an error

```
$("#result").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#result").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

API LINK: http://api.jquery.com/load/

sometimes the debugging information is a good first step to any solution.

Answer (score 3):

You have your script tags at the end of your page, which means the enclosed JS will be invoked as soon as the browser reaches it, which may not be before the DOM is ready (which means the `<ol>` might not be set up to get the content of test.html).  Try enclosing your load in a [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result').load('test.html');
});
</script>
```

Also why are you inserting a full HTML page into an ordered list?  You should try an HTML snippet (no head & body tags) into a content holder such as `<div>` or `<span>` where it will be semantically correct.

If none of these things work, attach a callback as follows:

```
$('#result').load('test.html', null, function(responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
    alert(textStatus); // see what the response status is
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is the closing script tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</head>
```

Your code needs to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I had two problems.  This was one of them.  Of course, I had tried it a number of times where I hadn't left the closing tag out before... just happened to miss it when I asked the question somehow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must first check if your HTML is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result').load('test.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure `#result1` is loaded, you need a `document.ready` event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result').load('test.html');
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers