# Jquery Refresh Not Refreshing Right

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I have a basic php page and it calls another php page that contains my mysql query and output. Pretty simple. I am using a jquery refresh statement below to auto refresh the div that the query is in:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#records').load('user_records.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 30000); // refresh every 30 seconds
</script>
```

Here is my user_records.php file:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['user'];
include('connect.php');
$did = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $user_id = $row['id'];
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM assign_did WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $did_id = $row['did_id'];
          $sql1 = "SELECT did FROM did WHERE id = '$did_id'";  
              $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
          while($row1 = $result1->fetch_row()){
                  $did[] = $row1[0];                  
          }
}
$did_arr = array();
foreach($did as $newdid){
    $did_arr[] = '`extension` LIKE \'%'.$newdid.'\'';
}
echo "<div id='records'><h1 align='center'>Today's Transfers</h1>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
<th> Customer Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Disposition</th><th>DID</th><th>Date Called</th>
</tr>
";
$sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM `vicidial_did_log` WHERE ('.implode(" OR ", $did_arr) . ')'; 
    $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $sql3, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
   while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
        $caller_id_number = $row3['caller_id_number'];
        $extension = $row3['extension'];
...echo the rows into rows and columns...
?>
```

So it refreshes user_records.php that has a div with id 'records'. That div performs the mysql query and echos is. My problem is that when it does the refresh, the query just goes blank. It refreshes the div, because I have a few things that echo/output before the query starts and starts outputting. Not sure what I am doing wrong here or what code you guys need to see. I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: `has a div with class 'records'` very conflicting when you use `$('#records')` typo?? or the answer should be `$('.records')`

Comment: You mean change #records to .records in the code above? I went off an example and it showed the # sign in front.

Comment: I meant the div had the id 'records', not class. my mistake.

Comment: OK you already updated it. Can you show your `user_records.php`

Comment: I added it above. It's just a table being echoed with a few queries in it.

Comment: in your file you used `$username = $_GET['user']` have you checked it your getting the right data?

Comment: on user_records.php u accessing $username = $_GET['user']; but u didnt giving parameter to ur URL from ur script

Comment: In my url is the $username variable. I know I get the data the first time properly, but maybe it's not getting the username once it does the refresh? The URl stays the same when it refreshes. I have: url.com?user=admin or whatever user i have up there.

Comment: Is your refresh function is in `$(document).ready();`

Comment: Not sure what you mean...Do I need to add that in my code?

Comment: @dkeeper09 check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899525/very-simple-jquery-load-example-not-working)

Comment: Adding the document.ready part didn't work. It didn't refresh at all when I added that part.